# Can't boot Ubuntu 19.04 or its LiveUSB after enrolling MOK

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 19.04, secure-boot

Before showing GRUB, it shows

> Unable to trigger tcg2 final events table: Invalid Parameter 
>   Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed 
>   : Invalid Parameter

and machine power off.

It's my first time to install Ubuntu 19.04 on this machine, DELL [T5810](https://www.dell.com/gy/business/p/precision-t5810-workstation/pd) with UEFI. The Ubuntu installation was fine, enrolling the [Machine Owner Key](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) [MOK](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) caused the boot error. When I ran `sudo apt install virtualbox`. virtualbox installation prompted me to enroll MOK; I rebooted the machine, and enrolled MOK. Then it entered the above dead state.

**Booting from Ubuntu's LiveUSB installer shows the same error message.** Luckily, I can still boot into Windows 10 on the same machine. I just want to revert enrolling MOK. Not installing Virtualbox in future is acceptable.

What I've tried:

1. Searching the error message leads to [mokutil](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mokutil.1.html), but I can't boot into Linux now.
2. I also tried to reset BIOS, but it doesn't work at all (I have to repair Windows boot).
3. Open EFI partition in Windows, deleted EFI/ubuntu, EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi, EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi.
4. I've deleted successful installed Ubuntu partition.
5. Tried Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB.
6. Upgrade BIOS to latest version from Dell website.
7. Delete and re-create EFI partition completely under Windows.

The first 3 partitions are

1. EFI
2. Windows
3. Ubuntu (has been removed)

Comment: Have you tried turning off UEFI Secure Boot? May be "Windows" or "Other" setting. may be similar:Dell Precision 5820 with PCI NVME SSD UEFI update & SSD firmware update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402254 MOK key only required for proprietary drivers with UEFI Secure boot on, as Ubuntu cannot make proprietary drivers signed, but  a user can if he believes software is safe.

Comment: Turning off Secure Boot doesn't fix the problem and I do want to use secure boot for my Windows.

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs. If UEFI Secure boot is on, you only have UEFI boot. With Secure boot off, you get two boot options in UEFI boot menu, one UEFI:flash and other flash where flash is name or label of flash drive.

Comment: Please make sure to clone your drive (using Clonezilla https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php or some other tool) to another drive of the same size or larger, to protect your Windows installation and all your data.

Comment: Thanks for reminder @K7AAY, but I can't afford large external storage or down time right now. The disk has 1T storage and the windows partition itself if 500G. I guess completely re-ceating EFI partition should work, but I'm not sure if I can fix Windows boot after complete deleting EFT partition. I'm trying this on a VM now.

Comment: Added a second bonus to try to draw more attention, after the first timed out.

Comment: @qxg is secure boot a requirement here? because it's causing issues clearly.

Comment: @tatsu, yes. It’s causing problem unexpectedly. I need some explanation and fix instead of workaround.

Comment: https://builders.intel.com/docs/networkbuilders/secure-the-network-infrastructure-secure-boot-methodologies.pdf may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my post and my own answer to an identical problem on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149920/cant-boot-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-or-its-liveusb-after-enrolling-mok).

The trick is to turn on TPM in bios settings. As I understand it, you need TPM ON or ACTIVE for storing and looking up keys. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: You saved me. Finally I switched my main working machine to Linux. Never go back.

Comment: Glad I could help! I did a lot of research on TPM before I came to the conclusion that it is necessary for storing keys for proprietary drivers. Thank you for confirming that turning TPM ON worked for you as well.